# Validating HTML form/web page element using VBScript

Tags: validation, vbscript

I have started to learn VBScript and I want to validate a HTML form / web page elements using VBScript .

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to refer an external HTML form/web page to the VBScript code and validate it's elements inside the script?

Like, I want to add a form reference or location (designed in HTML) in VBScript and validate its textbox, checkbox and submit it.

FYI, I can validate a HTML form simply by adding the VBScript part on the HTML code.

Example:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/vbscript">
         ...
        </SCRIPT>

        <FORM NAME="Form1">
            ...
        </FORM>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Simple Validation</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript"> 
<!--
Sub Submit_OnClick
  Dim TheForm
  Set TheForm = Document.ValidForm
  If IsNumeric(TheForm.Text1.Value) Then
    If TheForm.Text1.Value < 1 Or TheForm.Text1.Value > 10 Then
      MsgBox "Please enter a number between 1 and 10."
    Else
      MsgBox "Thank you."
    End If
  Else
    MsgBox "Please enter a numeric value."
  End If
End Sub
-->
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H3>Simple Validation</H3><HR>
<FORM NAME="ValidForm">
Enter a value between 1 and 10: 
<INPUT NAME="Text1" TYPE="TEXT" SIZE="2">
<INPUT NAME="Submit" TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Submit">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to validate a HTML form / web page elements using VBScript

This is very bad decision. Your solution will work only under Internet Explorer.

On client side strongly recomend to use JavaScript
On server sode of couse VBScript.